# Eagerloading a null in EF core gives an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can we handle scenarios when the **Include is getting a null** that has a **ThenInclude** for its **Child**?

```
_context.Bakery
.Include(p=>p.Parent) //Parent is null so there is an exception
.ThenInclude(c=>c.Child)
.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Here in the Bakery class:

```
public class Bakery
{
    public virtual SomeParent Parent {get;set;}
}
```

Here in the SomeParent class:

```
public class SomeParent 
{
    public virtual SomeChildren Child {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add null-forgiving operator "!" to your first include

```
_context.Bakery
   .Include(p=>p.Parent!) // <--
     .ThenInclude(c=>c.Child)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```